# calculate percentage inode usage using python

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to calculate percentage of inode usage in python.
Here is my sample python code

```
st = os.statvfs(path)
free  = (st.f_bavail * st.f_frsize) / 1024
total = (st.f_blocks * st.f_frsize) / 1024
used  = ((st.f_blocks - st.f_bfree) * st.f_frsize) / 1024
total_inode = st.f_files        # inodes 
free_inode = st.f_ffree   #free inodes 


# df -i /
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
none                 8257011   69850 8187161    1% /
```

but how to calculate %inode as shown in df -i command? i tried "total_inodes-free_inodes/total_inodes" but it is giving wrong percentage usage.

Comment: Did you do "total_inodes-free_inodes/total_inodes" or "(total_inodes-free_inodes)/total_inodes"?

Comment: i did "(total_inodes-free_inodes)/total_inodes

Comment: google sent me here because I wanted to know *how* to get the number of inodes in python (answer: `os.statvfs`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Python 2.x, `int` / `int` results in `int` floored. You should convert it to float first.

```
>>> 1/2
0
>>> 1.0/2
0.5
>>> float(1)/2
0.5
```

---

```
print(float(total_inode - free_inode) / total_inode)
```