# Inode usage without df -i

Tags: c, linux, bash, inode

I want to automate a remote proccess to know if a machine of mine is running out of inodes (something that happens quite often due to bad configuration...). Sadly it runs on a light weight linux that does not have -i option on the df command, so that option is unaviable. I have done some research and I have encountered some ways to find the folders with the most inodes and similar, but I don't want that.

I need a way (in C or bash) to know how many inodes my system has in total and currently aviable.

Comment: As for `C` source code you may take a part of `df.c` which is open source.
 http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/df.c;hb=refs/heads/master
 
 As for `bash` solution please take a look in other SO question
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/how-to-free-inode-usage

Comment: Could you use Perl http://search.cpan.org/~iguthrie/Filesys-Df-0.92/Df.pm or Python? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727179/calculate-percentage-inode-usage-using-python

Comment: I do have Perl but don't have python. I'll take a look at that solution. Ty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seek, is reported by the [`statvfs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/statvfs.3.html) function, for each mounted filesystem (specified by providing a path to any file or directory on said mounted filesystem).

If the system has GNU coreutils installed, it has a small utility called `stat`. For each path to a file or directory on a filesystem,

```
stat -c '%d %c' -f /path
```

reports the number of free inodes and the total number of inodes, one line per path given. If the system uses busybox, then

```
busybox stat -c '%d %c' -f /path
```

does the same thing.

If you need more control with the output, or neither of the above work for you for some reason, you can easily write your own utility to report a summary: 
Here is an example, **inode-stats.c**:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    dev_t       device[argc];
    int         devices = 0;
    uint64_t    total_inodes = 0;
    uint64_t    avail_inodes = 0; /* Free to normal users */
    uint64_t    free_inodes = 0;  /* Free to superuser */
    int         arg, i;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("       %s mountpoint [ mountpoint ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("\n");
        printf("This program will report the percentage of inodes in use,\n");
        printf("the number free inodes available for normal users,\n");
        printf("the number of free inodes available for root,\n");
        printf("and the total number of inodes,\n");
        printf("in the filesystems referred to the supplied paths.\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Each mount is only counted once, even if multiple paths\n");
        printf("to the same mount are given as parameters.\n");
        printf("\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        struct stat     info;
        struct statvfs  vfsinfo;

        if (stat(argv[arg], &info) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            continue;
        }
        if (statvfs(argv[arg], &vfsinfo) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            continue;
        }

        /* Check if device already seen. */
        for (i = 0; i < devices; i++)
            if (info.st_dev == device[i])
                break;
        if (i < devices)
            continue;

        /* Add to known devices. */
        device[devices++] = info.st_dev;

        /* Add to inode counters. */
        total_inodes += (uint64_t)vfsinfo.f_files;
        avail_inodes += (uint64_t)vfsinfo.f_favail;
        free_inodes  += (uint64_t)vfsinfo.f_ffree;
    }

    if (total_inodes < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No inodes!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Print result. */
    printf("%.3f%% - %" PRIu64 " free (%" PRIu64 " for root) out of %" PRIu64 " inodes.\n",
           100.0 - 100.0 * (double)avail_inodes / (double)total_inodes,
           avail_inodes, free_inodes, total_inodes);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile it using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -O2 inode-stats.c -o inode-stats
```

optionally install it using e.g.

```
sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 inode-stats /usr/bin
```

and run it, supplying a path to any directory or file in the mounts (mounted filesystems) you are interested in. For example,

```
inode-stats / /usr /var /home
```

The program is smart enough to only count mounts once, even if you supply multiple paths to directories/files in it -- unlike GNU coreutils' or busybox `stat`.

You can trivially change the output report format, and easily add other statistics (like free disk space, using `(uint64_t)vfsinfo.f_bavail * (uint64_t)vfsinfo.f_bsize` for amount of disk space available for normal users, and `(uint64_t)vfsinfo.f_blocks * (uint64_t)vfsinfo.f_frsize` for total size of each filesystem).

Comment: Neither stat or busybox stat works for me. I'll try that C solution and report later.

Comment: @J63: Please do; I could only test it on an x86-64 system, for now. You should also be able to cross-compile it to your target system in the normal fashion.

Comment: I compiled it to my target system and it just works fine. Thank you very much =)